# Is it possible to have visible element without height and width?

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom

I've been going through existing Selenium automation framework where it has a code which checks for width and height of an element. If they have positive values only then it will be interactable like click, double click etc.

```
public boolean isElementInteractable(WebElement element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String offsetWidth = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].offsetWidth;", element).toString();
    String offsetHeight = js.executeScript("return arguments[0].offsetHeight;", element).toString();

    if ((Integer.parseInt(offsetWidth) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(offsetHeight) != 0) && element.isDisplayed()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my understand, every element which is visible/interactable has positive height and width. I'm confused why this code has been written.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct? If not, please help me to understand the cases where this is possible.

Comment: You could have an element with 0 width and height but it overflows. It would still be visible but there is nothing to interact with as the element cannot be clicked

Comment: @ButchMonkey And then there is `Z-axis` as well :)

Answer (score 1):

`WebElement` must have width and height in order to be intractable, but it can be considered visible in two cases: it has positive stroke-width or they have child node/text node with positive size

From [WebDriver specifications Element displayedness](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#element-displayedness)

> The element displayed algorithm is a boolean state where true
>   signifies that the element is displayed and false signifies that the
>   element is not displayed. To compute the state on element, invoke the
>   Call(`bot.dom.isShown, null, element`).

From [bot.dom.isShown_](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/e09e28f016c9f53196cf68d6f71991c5af4a35d4/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L437) in github (line 437)

```
function positiveSize(e) {
    var rect = bot.dom.getClientRect(e);
    if (rect.height > 0 && rect.width > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    // A vertical or horizontal SVG Path element will report zero width or
    // height but is "shown" if it has a positive stroke-width.
    if (bot.dom.isElement(e, 'PATH') && (rect.height > 0 || rect.width > 0)) {
      var strokeWidth = bot.dom.getEffectiveStyle(e, 'stroke-width');
      return !!strokeWidth && (parseInt(strokeWidth, 10) > 0);
    }
    // Zero-sized elements should still be considered to have positive size
    // if they have a child element or text node with positive size, unless
    // the element has an 'overflow' style of 'hidden'.
    return bot.dom.getEffectiveStyle(e, 'overflow') != 'hidden' &&
        goog.array.some(e.childNodes, function(n) {
          return n.nodeType == goog.dom.NodeType.TEXT ||
                 (bot.dom.isElement(n) && positiveSize(n));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean from my following condition - `(Integer.parseInt(offsetWidth) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(offsetHeight) != 0) && element.isDisplayed()`, I can remove `width`, `height` part and can have condition like `element.isDisplayed()` or use explicit wait with visibility of element should be enough. Please confirm the same.

Comment: @TDHM  Explicit wait with visibility of element is enough. It also checks `element.isDisplayed()` internally (both `visibilityOf(WebElement)` and `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By)`). You can also use `elementToBeClickable()` but the only difference is it checks the `enabled` attribute which is usually true.

Comment: Thanks @Guy for confirmation!